# Can we do below problem by initializing hash's key with a default value?

Tags: ruby

Write a method that groups the above hash into 2 groups of 'even' and 'odd' length using 'inject'.
input - "['abc','def','1234','234','abcd','x','mnop','5','zZzZ']"

My code listed below already works. But I want to know better way to do it using default value for hash's key. I meant to say something like below -

```
h=Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = []}
```

Solution :

```
class Array
  def group_even_odd
    key_hash = group_by(&:length)
    key_array = %w(even odd)
    key_hash.each_with_object('odd' => [], 'even' => []) do |(key, value), even_odd_hash|
      even_odd_hash[key_array[key % 2]].push(value)
      even_odd_hash
    end
  end
end
if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
else
  input = ARGV[0].scan(/\w+/).map(&:to_s)
  puts input.group_even_odd
end
```

Expected and actual are same, code is working.

Expected result -
{"odd"=>[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]], "even"=>[["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does not meet the requirement that `inject` (aka `reduce`) be used, but it is how I would do it.

```
arr = ['abc', 'def', '1234', '234', 'abcd', 'x', 'mnop', '5', 'zZzZ']
```

```
odd, even = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |s,h|
  h[s.size] << s
end.
values.
partition { |a| a.first.size.odd? }
  #=> [[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]],
  #    [["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]]
{ "odd"=>odd, "even"=>even }    
  #=> {"odd"=>[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]],
  #    "even"=>[["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |s,h|
  h[s.size] << s
end
  #=> {3=>["abc", "def", "234"], 4=>["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"],
  #    1=>["x", "5"]} 
a = h.values
  #=> [["abc", "def", "234"], ["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"],
  #    ["x", "5"]]      
odd, even = a.partition { |a| a.first.size.odd? }
  #=> [[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]],
  #    [["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]]
{ "odd"=>odd, "even"=>even }
  #=> {"odd"=>[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]],
  #    "even"=>[["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]}
```

If one insists on fitting a square peg into a round hold (using `inject/reduce`), I suppose that could be done as follows.

```
arr.reduce({ "odd"=>[], "even"=>[] }) do |g,s|
  oe = s.size.odd? ? "odd" : "even"
  i = g[oe].find_index { |a| a.any? && a.first.size == s.size }
  case i.nil?
  when true then g[oe] << [s]
  else g[oe][i] << s
  end
  g
end
  #=> {"odd"=>[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]],
  #    "even"=>[["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]}
```

Comment: Thanks it was also a great add. Can someone please upvote this answer ? I do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Abhinav, best to wait until you can. :-)

Answer (score 2):

One possible option, given

```
ary = ["abc", "def", "1234", "234", "abcd", "x", "mnop", "5", "zZzZ"]
```

First group by even odd, then group by size:

```
ary.group_by { |e| e.size.even? ? 'even' : 'odd' }
   .transform_values { |v| v.group_by(&:size).values }

#= {"odd"=>[["abc", "def", "234"], ["x", "5"]], "even"=>[["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]]}
```

---

First step, to explain:

```
ary.group_by { |e| e.size.even? ? 'even' : 'odd' }
#=> {"odd"=>["abc", "def", "234", "x", "5"], "even"=>["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]}
```

Then [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) grouping each by size.

Comment: Abhinav, `Hash#transform_values` was introduced in Ruby v2.4. I suspect you might be using an earlier version.

Comment: ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: If upgrading is not an option, you can replace `.transform_values { |v| v.group_by(&:size).values }` with `.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = v.group_by(&:size).values }`.

Comment: Abhinav, it appears you have not made the change I mentioned in my comment on the question.

Comment: Very nice answer. I wasn't aware you could use `group_by` in the way that you have.

Comment: @iGian this answer was really very helpful .. thanks !